# Asynchronously show custom MessageBox, then all buttons in the most top MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, button, asynchronous, messagebox

I customize a `MessageBox`, in `MessageBox.cs`. In MainWindow, if click the button named `Open Two MessageBox`, then will start to run two `BackgroundWorker` respectively sleep 2000ms and 1000ms, and show the MessageBoxes. But you can find that:

[image]

the buttons in MessageBox1 goes into MessageBox2. I don't know why that?

These buttons are created and saveed in CtrlButtonCollection in MessageBoxModule.

I will go crazy by this problem.

Because of many code in the project, so I put it in GitHub.

*[The project in GitHub](https://github.com/SubmarineX/MessageBox)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always **avoid initializing of reference types in default metadata of Dependency property**. Since DP identifier registration is static, so this *reference will be shared across all instances of MessageBox*.

```
public static DependencyProperty CtrlButtonCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "CtrlButtonCollection",
                typeof(IList<Button>),
                typeof(MessageBoxModule),
                new PropertyMetadata(new List<Button>())); <-- HERE
```

Use other overload where you don't need to pass default metadata or pass null which is default value for all reference types i.e. declare like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty CtrlButtonCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "CtrlButtonCollection",
                typeof(IList<Button>),
                typeof(MessageBoxModule));
```

And do the initialization in its constructor:

```
public MessageBoxModule
{
    .....
    CtrlButtonCollectionProperty = new List<Button>();
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your MessageBoxModule.CtrlButtonCollectionProperty is static and so, it'll only register once and you'll have the same List() for all the message boxes you'll create.

Use non-static DependencyProperty to solve this problem.
(I'd also consider re-writing the whole thing).

Comment: If use non-static DependencyProperty, the vs will report error. How do you?